# Find the center coordinate of a circle from a list of pixel coordinates C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixel

I have a BitMap image where the image contains a black circle. I have found all the pixels from the image that are black which represent the circle and have saved the points into a List.

Where I am lost is finding the center of the circle from coordinates saved in the list. I am thinking that I need to find the diameter of the circle somehow but how do I loop though the pixels to do that to determine that?

Comment: Is it a filled circle or do the black pixels represent the border?

Comment: It is a filled circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One naive approach could be to find the bounding box for the circle.

Seeing as you already have all of the points in a list you can find the top, bottom, left and right.

Assuming the (0,0) is the top left of the co-ordinate system:

- The top is the point with min Y.
- The bottom is the point with max Y.
- The left is the point with min X.
- The right is the point with max X.

The center of the bounding box is the center of the circle.
Similarly the width/height of the bounding box is its diameter.

## Edit: an alternative solution

Find the mean of all the points in the circle.
This will then give you the center of the circle.

```
var aggregate = points.Aggregate((point, result) => new Point{ X = point.X + result.X, Y = point.Y + result.Y });
var center = new Point { X = aggregate.X / points.Count, Y = aggregate.Y / points.Count };
```

This may be a more optimal solution because it could be done while you are scanning the image for the black pixels. Rather than finding the black pixels and then using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Circle is a relative term when it comes to images, that's to say, that the shape you are referring to is shown in pixels and may only be representative of a circle.

However to get the midpoint all you need to do is get the extents.

Assuming you have a `List<Point>`

```
var left = list.Min(x => x.X);
var right = list.Max(x => x.X);
var top= list.Min(x => x.Y);
var bottom = list.Max(x => x.Y);

Point mid = new Point();
mid.X = left + (right-left) / 2; //calculate mid point x
mid.Y = top + (bottom-top) / 2; //calculate mid point y
```

***Note*** : Totally untested